# Sharepoint Task Items Title Field - change URL to point at a custom form

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, task-list

I am currently developing a custom workflow which has it's own approval process when publishing documents to a list.
I have created a new form for use which approves/rejects the file. The approval form successfully works and I am sending out the link for it to the approver. My problem is that on creation of the task list item I also want to change the url that is attached to the Sharepoint Built in Field "Title". I cannot find this anywhere within either the Task Properties object or within Extended properties.

Does anyone know if I can set this property, something like:

`createApproval_TaskProperties.ExtendedProperties["Title URL"] = "http://url/"`

Or is this something you can't edit, and would have to create my own custom content type to hold the Title/link to my custom approval form, then Hide sharepoints "Title" Column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build my own custom content type with a new URL field. That way you don't change the default Title field. And the custom content type will be specific to that workflow.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for taking so long to reply, this worked though :)

Comment: You can mark this as your answer.

Comment: 9 years later. :O

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a List with a List Schema (Template) where you can specify which Forms are to be used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543477.aspx

Refer to Forms Element.

You can do it manually using Sharepoint Manager 2010 or similar tool.

Hope it helps!

Best Regards